# Is the if statement necessary in the canonical enumerator MoveNext function?

Tags: delphi

The canonical MoveNext in a Delphi enumerator is written like this:

```
function TListEnumerator.MoveNext: Boolean;
begin
  Result := FIndex < FList.Count - 1;
  if Result then
    Inc(FIndex);
end;
```

This is the form used throughout the RTL, VCL etc. This form appears to be widespread in 3<sup>rd</sup> party code also.

I think it can be written more simply like this:

```
function TListEnumerator.MoveNext: Boolean;
begin
  Inc(FIndex);
  Result := FIndex < FList.Count;
end;
```

Is there any good reason why the simpler form cannot be used?

---

My reasoning is as follows. Once `MoveNext` returns `False`, the `Current` property is never accessed again. It doesn't matter that `FIndex` is off the end of the list since it is never used again. The for in loop is actually implemented like this:

```
while Enumerator.MoveNext do
  Enumerator.Current.DoSomething;
```

In fact it actually makes more sense to me that `FIndex` goes out of bounds. It means that if anyone uses hand-written enumerator code then they will get range check errors in case `Current` is accessed after `MoveNext` returns `False`.

What's more, `FIndex` is `-1` before the first call to `MoveNext`. That is one off the list to the left. And after the final call to `MoveNext`, the one that returns `False`, isn't it appropriate that `FIndex` is `Count`, that is one off the list to the right.

Comment: In your version, you can get out of bounds with the `FIndex`, don't you ?

Comment: @TLama You don't call `GetCurrent` once `MoveNext` has returned `False`. And if you did, out of bounds is what you want. You don't want to get the last item for a second time. To my mind this is the mirror image of the initial state where `FIndex` is `-1`.

Comment: The reason of *don't you* at the end of my comment was just because I don't know `TListEnumerator` and its intention at all. I was just hoping in your weak moment...

Comment: Interesting: TListEnumerator.MoveNext has the implementation from your question. Have a look at TList<T>.TEnumerator.MoveNext. It's different. And has an "off-by-one" difference with the non-generic enumerator. Using the non-generic one, FIndex doesn't move beyond Count-1, using the generic one it doesn't move beyond Count and so GetCurrent can actually throw an EArgumentOutOfRange error. Consistency failure if you ask me...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're assuming `TListEnumerator` will only ever be used in a `for` loop. Although that will be by far the most common case, your suggested version can misbehave when it isn't. It's just fine to call `MoveNext` again after it has already returned `False` once. If you continue calling `MoveNext` until it returns `True`, you must get an infinite loop, and with your suggested version, the loop won't be infinite, it'll terminate once you're past the `FIndex = MaxInt` case.

See the documentation for [`IEnumerator.MoveNext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerator.movenext.aspx), which Delphi's implementation is based on (IIRC, it was actually first available in the now dead Delphi .NET):

> When the enumerator is at this position, subsequent calls to MoveNext also return false until Reset is called.

Comment: OK, but there is no `Reset` in a Delphi enumerator. And as it happens, I only want for in for enumerators I write.

Comment: That just means that for a Delphi enumerator, it simplifies to "subsequent calls to MoveNext also return false", without the "until" part. :)

Comment: I don't really accept that rules for a different language apply here. But that rule could be a reason why Delphi MoveNext implementations look the way they do.

Comment: It's not rules for a different language, it's rules for a different environment, which at one point Delphi could compile for. It was required at that point in time, and whether by accident or by design, it was never changed after support for that environment was dropped. About your edited comment: if your implementation is 100% compatible for the uses that actually occur in your program, then it's fine for your program.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan There is Reset in Delphi enumerators, just not in the generic one! Which I think is a huge omission on Embarcadero's part. They have neglected to keep both versions of the Enumerators in sync. Had they made the generic TEnumerator abstract class implement IEnumerator, they would have been told to implement Reset by their own compiler. Why they "forgot" to make the generic enumerator implement the proper interface is beyond me...

Comment: @marjan I imagine IEnumerator is for .net compatibility and so needs a Reset. The other enumerator classes in the RTL etc. serve for in and attempt no more. Jon Skeet in C# in Depth argues that Reset should not have been included in .net's IEnumerator.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I agree with that, as implementations of `Reset` are allowed to unconditionally throw `NotSupportedException`, and there's no way to check beforehand whether they support it, so it doesn't really add anything. The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerator.reset.aspx) even says so: "The Reset method is provided for COM interoperability. It does not necessarily need to be implemented; instead, the implementer can simply throw a NotSupportedException."

Comment: The .net rules for Current are interesting. They state "Current also throws an exception if the last call to MoveNext returned false, which indicates the end of the collection."

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: well, come to think of it, yes, I guess Reset might not be necessary, but somehow, knowing the innards, I would like to be able ensure a fresh start with Reset when iterating over a enumerator twice... I know I can get another enumerator for that, but in code that needs to be extremely performant, that seems wasteful (instantiating versus "just" an assignment to FIndex).

Comment: @Marjan If performance matters, using a branch free MoveNext is going to have more impact than the very unusual case of re-using an enumerator. Speaking of performance, I hate the fact that Emba's enumerators are implemented as classes rather than records.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: D'oh... of course. Luckily I can claim a very bad cold for my cloudy judgement... And yes, records would have been better!

Comment: @Marjan Hallvard Vassbotn wrote an article discussing enumerator performance. He made the point about records/classes in the RTL. He submitted a QC report which was declined as won't do. Perhaps this dates from .net days when they needed to use classes in order to implement interfaces.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: thanks I'll dig that up. At work I am currently struggling with combining the generics with interfaced classes, much fun. To do so, I have to make our own iterator and if I can get it as performant as possible that would be great. Fun fact: I just copied your sentence into Google search and the article came right up... :-)

Comment: @Marjan I've been struggling with some similar sounding puzzles of late. I ended up with a rather surprising design. Not sure if I got it right. The SO expert on the subject is Stefan Glienke if memory serves. May be worth looking at his open source work. Think it's the Delphi dependency injection framework. I mean to do the same.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Seems we are on similar tracks then. I am indeed doing our own version of dependency injection. No framework as yet because I need to keep it very lightweight. But thanks for the reminder. Had forgotten about Delphi DI. Certainly worth looking at Stefan's work!

Answer (score 2):

Thinking purely semantically, I would say the original version is correct. Think of it like a conversation:

```
Application: Hey, list. Go to the next item.
List: No, sorry. I can't.
Application: Oh, allright.
  <some time later:>
Application: List, please give me the current item
List: No problem, here you go.


Whereas in your suggestion, it would go like this:


Application, Hey, list. Go to the next item.
List: No, that's impossible.
Application: Oh, all right.
  <some time later:>
Application: Hi again, List. Give me the current item.
List: Here you go. 
Application: Thanks, mate.
  <some time later, when using the item:>
Application: What the ????!
```

Comment: The problem with that is that in the first conversation, the program gives you an item that has already been consumed. Which would be no good. And in the second conversation, WTF is the appropriate response. Neither happens, to the best of my knowledge, since once `MoveNext` returns `False`, the enumerator is never asked for the current item again. What I'm looking for here is a refutation of that analysis. This isn't it.

Comment: That raises the question if items are always "consumed" when moving next. I suppose this is often the case, when iterating through a list etc, but always? If i use the enumerator to "navigate back and forth" through some data, I think I would prefer that the pointer always was valid.

Comment: In which case you'd also presumably initialise the enumerator by setting `FIndex` to 0 rather than -1. Is that correct?

Comment: Well, more like a GoFirst procedure or something, but yeah. The problem with my answer vs your question is that we talk about two somewhat different things. My argument was about navigating lists _in general_, your question was _specifically_ about _enumerators_ (which I suppose you only use to "consume" items).

Comment: Yep, I am talking about Delphi enumerators as used by for in.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: the delphi enumerators start at -1 because of the `for in` implementation: `while MoveNext do`. If you want your enumerators to return valid items on GetCurrent at all times, you will need to address this in your implementation of MoveNext, making sure it doesn't move on the first, but does on the second... I don't like the way the delphi enumerators are implemented, but I wouldn't advise going against them. That is a sure fire way of creating some major headaches.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question (+1). Without knowledge of all possible uses of enumerators (or its use at all), at first sight it sure looks odd that its functioning differs between the begin and the end of the list. As you say: `Current` results in a *List index out of bounds* error at the beginning, then why not at the end? Seems inconsistent.

But thinking about it a little further: once an enumerator is created, by what- or whoever, the list's bounds are not known, so the first element is not and cannot be selected yet. This in comparison to the behaviour at the end when the bounds are known and the index is limited to.

Datasets function exactly in the same way, but the implementation of enumerators could probably benefit from `BOF`- and `EOF`-like behaviour.